# Screen compatible issue in flutter application for different screen size device

Tags: flutter, media-queries, padding

How to calculate padding of the particular widget using `MediaQuery` class?
It should compatible to all the different screen devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, MediaQuery doesn't tell you what you need to know.  LayoutBuilder gives you the constraints of the parent widget.  You would use it at the top-level to decide whether to use a one or two column layout, and further down to decide how sub-panes are laid out.  But you'll probably get some value by understanding the phrase "constraints are passed down, sizes are passed up, and then the layout is computed from top down."  This is explained better in https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints.